# Clarify definitions of relation and 0-ary relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

From [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Relation.html):

> A relation is any subset of a Cartesian product

But if so, then the null set is all of: 0-ary, 1-ary, 2-ary etc. Wouldn't it be better to define it as:

> A relation is any **non-empty** subset of a Cartesian product

Second question, from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273371) I understand that in set theory a 0-ary function is commonly taken to mean $\{ \emptyset \}$, also called a constant. If a 0-ary relation is a non-empty subset of some set $D^{0}$ ($D$ is the domain), isn't it right to say a 0-ary relation is also a constant? I haven't seen model theory texts include 0-ary relations, which makes sense as they're including 0-ary functions instead. To be technically the same as 0-ary functions (as they're defined in the linked answer), wouldn't we have to define relation as:

> An n-ary relation is any **non-empty** subset of $D^{\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}}$

What do you think?

**EDIT:** I should add that you can still define the empty set to be a relation of arity 0. From the comments below it seems it's a matter of convenience more than technical correctness as to how relations are defined.

Comment: Why do you not want to consider empty relations? They're quite useful, and they don't cause any problems.

Comment: Well you could separately define a null set to be a relation too right (of arity 0)? This way it's arity is clear, but in the standard definition, its not.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. You believe that a relation should necessarily come along with information about the sets it relates. Bourbaki and some other authors share your concern. So instead of defining a binary relation between sets $E$ and $F$ as a subset $\Gamma$ of $E \times F$, they define it as a triple $(\Gamma, E, F)$. But others feel this formalism creates more problems than it solves. *Nobody* would do away with empty relations, however. If you had two relations $R$ and $S$, it wouldn't always be possible to consider the relation $R \cap S$.

Comment: I don't understand how a 0-ary relation is a constant. Also, I've never seen a case where the ambiguity of the arity of the empty relation leads to confusion; do you have an example?

Comment: A $0$-ary relation would be a relation that didn't depend on any variables. So it would have to be either always true or always false. Technically, a $0$-ary relation would be defined as a subset of the product of the empty collection of sets. This product is $\{\varnothing\}$. So there are two $0$-ary relations, namely $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$. The first corresponds to "false" and the second to "true."

Comment: Careful: a 0-ary *function*, not a 0-ary *relation*, is a constant, because it maps a single element (the empty set) to a specific element in the codomain.

Comment: NoahSchweber: I don't have an example, I'm just a beginner wondering why no one mentioned 0-ary relations in the texts, which led me to wonder how they're different from 0-ary functions. 

David yes so  it seems like a 0-ary relation would be a constant too right? It's just never mentioned that way.

Comment: @NotGauss How would a 0-ary relation be a constant? Suppose my structure is the set of positive real numbers - what positive real number does either 0-ary relation correspond to?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I rolled them into an answer. If you have the time, I'd really appreciate if you could read through it and point out errors, if any. I don't have a teacher, so this will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to put together the answers/comments so far, and explain my own source of confusion. I am a novice, so please feel free to correct my mistakes, I shall be grateful for the education :)

*First*, I should more clearly state my "alternate" definition of a relation:

> 1. $\emptyset$ is a relation with arity 0
> 2. Every element of 
>       $\mathcal{P}(D^n) \setminus \emptyset$ 
>       is a relation of arity n

The point was to clearly specify the arity of $\emptyset$. This definition exchanges convenience for that extra "clarity". Note: It still allows two 0-ary sets: 
$\emptyset$ by definition, and 
$\mathcal{P}(D^0)\setminus \emptyset = \{ \emptyset \}$.
This was what @David was saying. This was just a technical exercise, not worth it in practice I realized.

*Second*, I was sloppy in reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/273371). It says $S^0$ is $\{ \emptyset \}$, but a 0-ary operator maps $S^0$ to an element in $S$, so a 0-ary operator is $\{ (\emptyset, a) \}$ where $a \in S$. This is what @mrp was saying. I suppose this can be extended to define a general 0-ary function <strike>on</strike> **into** any non-empty set $A$ as $\{ (\emptyset,a) \}$ for $a \in A$.

*Third*, because of my sloppiness, I assumed a 0-ary function is $\{ \emptyset \}$ rather than $\{ (\emptyset,a) \}$, equating a 0-ary relation to a 0-ary function.

*Fourth*, I considered the definition of a 0-ary relation outside the context of model theory, leading to above definition. Inside model theory of course, we separate syntax and semantics. I think what @NoahSchweber is saying is that if we call some symbol a 0-ary function, it is mapped to an object in the domain (hence, 0-ary function symbols are called constant symbols too), while if we call the same symbol a 0-ary relation it should be mapped to $\{ \emptyset \}$ or $ \emptyset$, rather than an object in the domain.

*Fifth*, I think that calling a 0-ary function a constant symbol is strictly incorrect. When we talk of a constant symbol, we usually have in mind something that maps to an object in the domain, let's say $a$ maps to $a^\mathfrak{M}$. But as we found above, a 0-ary function $a$ should actually map to $\{ (\emptyset, a^\mathfrak{M}) \}$, not $a^\mathfrak{M}$. So perhaps, Wilfrid Hodges' [definition](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Rf6GWut4D30C&lpg=PR3&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false) is right in this sense (pg. 2 of his big book "Model Theory"). He restricts function and relation symbols to arity $\geq$ 1, and defines constant symbols as a different entity.

*Sixth*, we could perhaps "simulate" sentential logic in first order logic using 0-ary relations. Namely, having symbols $\{ P_1, P_2, \ldots \}$ be 0-ary relation symbols, mapped to $\emptyset$ if we want them to be false, and to $\{ \emptyset \}$ if we want them to be true, based on @MauroAllegranza's answer. The language would consist of no other symbols. The reason is: $R(a_1, \ldots,  a_n)$ is true if the n-tuple $(a_1^\mathfrak{M}, \ldots,  a_n^\mathfrak{M}) \in R^\mathfrak{M}$. So, for a 0-ary relation symbol $P_1$, $P_1$ is true if the 0-tuple $\emptyset \in P_1^\mathfrak{M}$ which is true if $P_1$ maps to $\{ \emptyset \}$ and false otherwise. Wikipedia says [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Non-logical_symbols) too:

> Relations of valence 0 can be identified with propositional variables. For example, P, which can stand for any statement.

Comment: Since there are no errors pointed out so far, I am assuming this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is adopted in Bruno Poizat, [A Course in Model Theory: An Introduction to Contemporary Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=_WXgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32) (2000 - ed or 1985), page 32-33:

> *Note*: In certain cases, it can be convenient to introduce $0$-ary relations. 
>   As a function from $X$ to $Y$ associates to every element of $X$ one and only 
>   one element of $Y$, there is always one function from $\emptyset$ to $E$, *whether or not $E$ is empty*. The graph of this function is $\emptyset$; in other words, there is one $0$-tuple of elements of $E$. Consequently, there are always two nullary relations with universe $E$, namely $\{ \emptyset \}$ and $\emptyset$; the first can be called the *true*, the second *the false*. In contrast, if $m > 0$, there are no $m$-tuples of elements of $\emptyset$, and therefore only one $m$-ary relation with universe $\emptyset$, which is $\emptyset$. (We have often said that $\emptyset$ is always a local isomorphism between two $m$-ary relations for $m > 0$.)
>
> A nullary relation symbol is therefore interpreted in a structure either by 
>   the true or by the false. These nullary relations are not very interesting in 
>   and of themselves, but occur naturally as a calculation tool: If a formula in 
>   $n$ free variables represents an $n$-ary relation (the set of $n$-tuples that satisfy it), a statement represents a $0$-ary relation, either the true or the false.

Comment: Wow, finally a book that talks about this! Thanks for pointing it out. I'm writing an answer/summary of comments so far, and I think this will fit in well.

Comment: I added an answer. If you have time, perhaps you could read over it, and point out mistakes if any. Thanks!